# iOS and bluetooth numeric keyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, bluetooth

I have a question about detect and change input from bluetooth numeric keyboard and sending text to another applications.

My customer asked me, if it's possible this:

- my customer has bluetooth numeric keyboard and he wants to use it like phone keyboard (that means one press of number 1 it's letter A, double press it's letter B etc.)
- he wants this behavior of keyboard in general for all of applications in iPhone (in email app, SMS app etc.)

I'm not sure, but i think that it's not possible, because i think the application on background cant't modify key input for another apps. Or is here any way how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may be possible via a jailbreak app but definitely wouldn't be possible using the regular SDK.

If this isn't meant as a mass market tool, perhaps jail breaking is an option? I would check this out and see if it's any help http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileSubstrate

Comment: I thought that here isn't any legal way, how to do it without jailbreak.  Thank you